# How to find and delete unused indexes in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

Am pretty much new to Database activity. We are using Oracle 19C and am having only SQL Developer with me. I have a task to find and remove unused indexes from all tables of a particular owner (say owner=QTSD). Am using below query:

```
select * from ALL_INDEXES where owner='QTSD';
```

From the result, am checking LAST_ANALYZED column and then which was analyzed last year those indexes I will drop it one by one. Is this the correct way to implement? Also does deleting the indexes need DB downtime as corresponding tables have ~100millions of data?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that it was last analyzed a long time ago doesn't mean much. Why didn't you analyze it more often?

The optimizer decides whether to use and index or not. You can monitor its usage by e.g.

```
alter index my_index monitoring usage;
```

Do that index-by-index (if there are some really suspicious), or write a script which will write that for you:

```
select 'alter index ' || index_name || ' monitoring usage;' from user_indexes;
```

Copy/paste that script to execute them all.

Then wait some time (how long? I can't tell, might take a lot of time until many SQLs have been executed in the database so that you'd actually gather some statistics about the usage), and then query **v$object_usage**; pay attention to the `USED` column value.

After that, you'll be somewhat *smarter* (meaning: you won't be just lucky guessing whether some index was used or not) and, hopefully, be able to drop unused indexes.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use database index monitoring features in order to find unused index.
See [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/index-monitoring) if you are on version 12.1 or lower. See [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/index-usage-tracking-12cr2) If your DB is 12.2 or newer